# How to trigger Local Notifications in Ionic 4 when force sensor reach certain level?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic4, ionic-native

I have an ESP32 WEMOS lolin board and a force sensor. So far I've connected my board via bluetooth and can get readings from the sensor but this time I want my app to get notifications whenever my app receives a certain value. I was thinking using a variable **seconds** with a default value of 1 year and whenever my device receives a **value n** from the sensor I'll just change the seconds to 1 and the notification will display or perhaps using **update()** instead? But so far this is my code on the notifications.

```
  displayNotifs(){
    this.localNotifs.schedule({
      id: 3123,
      text: "Do something",
      trigger:{ in: this.seconds, unit: ELocalNotificationTriggerUnit.SECOND }
    });

  getReading(reading){
    if(reading == 1){
      this.seconds = 1;
    }
  }
```

I've looked into the local notifications documents [here](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) and other triggers include date and locations. Does anyone know any documents about the different types of trigger or any suggestions/tutorials how to implement what I'm trying to do? Thank you